# Google datastore entity creation and update

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to update an entity in my datastore kind using sample code from here https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries. The actual code is something like this:

```
/ Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
});

// The kind for the new entity
const kind = 'Task';
// The name/ID for the new entity
const name = 'sampletask1';
// The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, name]);

// Prepares the new entity
const task = {
  key: taskKey,
  data: {
    description: 'Buy milk',
  },
};

// Saves the entity
datastore
  .save(task)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`Saved ${task.key.name}: ${task.data.description}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

I tried to **create a new entity** using this code. But when I ran this code and checked the datastore console, there were **no entitites created**.Also, I am unable to update an existing entity. What could be the reason for this?

I am writing the code in Google Cloud Functions.This is the log when I run this function:

```
 {
 insertId: "-ft02akcfpq"  
 logName: "projects/test-66600/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
 operation: {…}  
 protoPayload: {…}  
 receiveTimestamp: "2018-06-15T09:36:13.760751077Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "NOTICE"  
 timestamp: "2018-06-15T09:36:13.436Z"  
}

{
 insertId: "000000-ab6c5ad2-3371-429a-bea2-87f8f7e36bcf"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/test-66600/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2018-06-15T09:36:17.865654673Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Intializing firebase-admin may fail"  
 timestamp: "2018-06-15T09:36:09.434Z"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code and it works for me. However, I have noticed that there was a delay before the entities appeared in Datastore. In order to update and overwrite existing entities,  use `.upsert(task)` instead of `.save(task)` [(link to GCP documentation)](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#creating_an_entity). You can also use `.insert(task)` instead of `.save(task)` to store new entities.

Also check that the project id is correct and that you are inspecting the entities for the right kind.

Comment: Thanks for the response Phillipp. I tried both your approaches and waited for about 15 minutes, since you mentioned you experienced a delay. However, I am yet to see the changes on the console. Could it be an issue with my package.json?

Comment: Also, I am looking for the changes in the 'description' box of the 'property' of the entity. Is that where the changes are reflected?

Comment: Yes, that is where a change will be reflected if you use upsert for an entity that already exists in the Datastore. You do not see any entries in the Datastore still? Can you add the entities manually from the GCP console like it is described in this quickstart ?  https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/quickstart

Comment: I tried adding entities manually and they do get updated. But, my intention is to do this automatically via code in the Cloud Functions. Could you please let me know where you wrote your code? As in, on your local system or on the cloud?

Comment: You sent me this link in your answer: [link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#creating_an_entity). I couldn't figure out what the parameters 'category','done' and 'priority' mean. Could you please shed some light on it?

Comment: An entity has one or more named properties, each of which can have one or more values - 'category','done' and 'priority' are such properties that you can give to the entity. That link explains everything about entities. To answer your second question, I launched a Cloud Function, same as you, and it worked for me. If you are still having issues with entities appearing in the Cloud Datastore, I suggest you open a support ticket, since this would need more investigation.